# Reference field in MySQL SET Query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table that looks something likes this

```
+----+----------------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+
| id | fullname             | email                    | username | password |
+----+----------------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+
|  1 | John Doe             | johndoe@example.com      | johndoe  | password |
|  2 | Jane Doe             | janedoe@example.com      | janedoe  | password | 
+----+----------------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+
```

What I want to do is change "password" to "1". So example, the table would look like this after that query:

```
+----+----------------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+
| id | fullname             | email                    | username | password |
+----+----------------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+
|  1 | John Doe             | johndoe@example.com      | johndoe  | johndoe1 |
|  2 | Jane Doe             | janedoe@example.com      | janedoe  | janedoe1 | 
+----+----------------------+--------------------------+----------+----------+
```

I tried doing `UPDATE table SET password=username+"1" WHERE id=1;` but that didn't work. No surprise there.

How would I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to use the where condition?

Comment: @VJHil that was for a test so I didn't have to undo mistakes. Yes, I wouldn't need a WHERE clause if I was doing this for the entire table.

Comment: Be careful with storing passwords....you generally want to use a proper hashing method against them before storing...

Comment: @user2366842 in an ideal world, yes. However, this is just an internal project. It isn't accessible to any users outside the network and it never will be. Yes, password encryption is important, and it is worth mentioning, but it does not apply to the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
UPDATE table SET password=CONCAT(username,'1') ;
```

### [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51795)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. Will mark as best answer after timer counts down.